# Random Button enabling in Android

Tags: android, button, resources

I need to enable a `button` using a random number. The names of the buttons are button1, button2, button3. Here's my code:

```
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            b.setBackgroundColor(R.color.redwue);

            setNextButton(b);
        }
    });


public void setNextButton(Button str){

    System.out.println("&&&&&&&&&&& SETNEXTBUTTON");
    str.setEnabled(false);
    int zufall = (int) (Math.random()*2);
    int buttonid = str.getId(); 
    int buttonname = (int) str.getId();
    System.out.println("&&&&&&&&&&&" +  getResources().getResourceEntryName(buttonid));
    Button bnew = new Button(this);
    bnew.setTag(buttonname);
    System.out.println("&&&&&&&&&&&" +  getResources().getResourceEntryName(bnew.getId()));
    bnew.setEnabled(true);
```

Now with this solution, I get an `Unable to find resource id` error. I know why that is but I can't find a solution for how to randomly enable a different `button`?

Comment: you want to do some different action when one of the button clicked and some other action when any other button clicked?

Comment: I want if one button is clicked to disable this and enable a random other button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a Button is created by `Button bnew = new Button(this);` no id is assigned to that Button. You must do it by yourself:

```
bnew.setId(yourId);
```

Create an array that save the id for all buttons you want to work. Match the randon number with the position on array to get the id for that button.

```
int[] buttonIds = {R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3};
Button bnew = (Button) findViewById(buttonIds[zufall]);
bnew.setEnabled(true);
```

You must ensure zufall is in [0, buttonIds.length - 1] range

Comment: Ok but button2 and button3 already have an ID. With bnew I only want to access one of these two, randomly.